# How do I find distinct time periods of context around instants in R?

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I'm starting from a set of log timestamps and want to produce a set of non-overlapping time periods so that I can show the corresponding log entries in some context.

Assuming I have a list of datetimes in R:

```
times <- c("2015-03-10 19:13:35", 
           "2015-03-10 19:13:37", 
           "2015-03-10 19:15:20", 
           "2015-03-10 19:16:40", 
           "2015-03-10 19:16:45")
```

I'd like to produce a list of time periods spanning 10s either side of those dates, without overlaps. For example:

```
[1] "2015-03-10 19:13:25" -- "2015-03-10 19:13:47"
[2] "2015-03-10 19:15:10" -- "2015-03-10 19:15:30"
[3] "2015-03-10 19:16:30" -- "2015-03-10 19:16:55"
```

- [1] Starts 10s before times[1], and ends 10s after times[2] (because they're within 10s of each other)
- [2] Is just 10s each side of times[3] because that doesn't overlap with the other periods
- [3] Starts 10s before times[4] and ends 10s after times[5] (they're close again)

I've made an attempt using lubridate, I can create the time periods (admittedly the easy part). How do I merge overlapping periods?

```
intervals <- as.interval(new_difftime(second=20), ymd_hms(times) - 10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's How I would approach this using base R

```
times <- as.POSIXct(times) # Convert your times to POSIXct class
Myfunc <- function(x) { 
                      temp <- range(x) ; 
                      c(min = temp[1] - 10, max = temp[2] + 10)
} # Create a range function
indx <- cumsum(c(0, diff(times)) > 10) # Create an index which separate the 
tapply(times, indx, Myfunc)  # Run the whole thing
# $`0`
#                       min                       max 
# "2015-03-10 19:13:25 IST" "2015-03-10 19:13:47 IST" 
# 
# $`1`
#                       min                       max 
# "2015-03-10 19:15:10 IST" "2015-03-10 19:15:30 IST" 
# 
# $`2`
#                       min                       max 
# "2015-03-10 19:16:30 IST" "2015-03-10 19:16:55 IST"
```

---

Or if you prefer the result in a more robust structure, I would go with `data.table` (apparently `aggregate` doesn't preserve `POSIXct` class for some reason)

```
df <- data.frame(times, indx)
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, as.list(Myfunc(times)), by = indx]
#    indx                 min                 max
# 1:    0 2015-03-10 19:13:25 2015-03-10 19:13:47
# 2:    1 2015-03-10 19:15:10 2015-03-10 19:15:30
# 3:    2 2015-03-10 19:16:30 2015-03-10 19:16:55
```